# calculate carriage on javascript invoice

Tags: javascript, jquery

Given the following: How would I go about making a function to calculate carriage based on user input (which I have already created with the id "carriage")?

```
/* Description: Update price function
 *  @param: $itemRow - Row Object
 **/
var updatePrice = function ($itemRow) {

  // Calculate the price of the row.  Remove and $ so the calculation doesn't break
  var price = $itemRow.find('#itemPrice').val().replace(",", "") * $itemRow.find('#itemQty').val();
  var carriage = $itemRow.find('#carriage').val();

  price = roundNumber(price, 2);
  isNaN(price) ? $itemRow.find('#itemLineTotal').val("N/A") : $itemRow.find('#itemLineTotal').val(price);
  update_total();

};


var update_total = function () {

  var total = 0;

  $('input#itemLineTotal').each(function (i) {
    price = $(this).val().replace(",", "");
    if (!isNaN(price)) total += Number(price);
  });

  total = roundNumber(total, 2);

  $('input#invGrandTotal').val('\u20AC' + total);

};
```

Comment: What you want is not clear?

Comment: What is *carriage* in the context you're using it?

Comment: it is an additional field in the form the user inputs and in turn that will update the total

Comment: What exactly is $itemRow? Is it a jQuery object of a table row? In this case you should consider using classes instead of IDs because IDs should be unique in your whole HTML document (same with #itemLineTotal)

Answer (score 0):

First, some improvements your code:

- You seem to use the same ID for inputs in multiple HTML table rows. HTML allows you to use an ID only once per document. In your case you should use classes instead of IDs.
- You remove commas in all numbers. It is not clear if this is correct or not. Do you use the comma as thousands separator (then it is okay) or as decimal separator (then it is not)? This depends on your local number format.
- You don't need the (custom?) function `roundNumber()`, you can use `Number.toFixed()` e.g. `10.toFixed(2)` returns `10.00`
- In your `update_total()` function you remove the commas again, but you never added them when writing to each row's `itemLineTotal` field.
- I recommend you to use a consistent coding style, e.g. you sometimes use camel case function names (`updatePrice()`), sometimes an underscore (`update_total()`).

In your code example, it looks like there is one `carriage` input per row. As this is not very common on invoices, I assumed that this was a mistake and there is only one such input in the whole invoice.

To calculate the grand total you have to calculate the sum of all `itemLineTotal`s and then add the value of `carriage`. You should do that in `update_total()`. I created a fiddle which shows a working example, hope that helps:

http://jsfiddle.net/pascalockert/8G7mp/

(Perhaps you have to adapt the decimal and thousands separators as mentioned above. See lines 10, 11, 21 and 25. Also, please mind JavaScript's restrictions on floating point numbers)